# Angular and ADFS

Tags: java, angular, spring, single-sign-on, adfs

I have an angular webapp that communicates with a java backend through rest services.
This webapp has a login screen linked to a user table.

Now I should link this webapp with a company's ADFS service to implement SSO.
The company only provided me with federationmetadata.xml
What is the best procedure to make this connection?
NB: ADFS must pass me email and group, to login in my webapp and then show certain contents based on the role of the user.

Thank you

Comment: I can't understand why I find very few examples on the net. maybe I'm doing my research wrong?

Comment: Have you seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs

Comment: yes I read this too. but they make use of Azure AD. I don't own Azure.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. This is a sample originally intended for azure AD that is customised for adfs. What is the blocker here?

Comment: ah, ok i had read wrong.
so by registering the client on adfs I can use ADAL.js or MSAL.js without using Azure right?
But what is the difference between this way and the "relying party trust" using the customer's SAML?

Comment: The link I gave uses OAuth2 and OpenID Connect which are protocols designed to be easier to use with REST APIs compared to SAML. Instead of a relying party you end up creating application groups instead. I hope your AD FS is at least Windows Server 2016.

Comment: ok thanks, but when you use "relying party trust" how do you manage everything? I found nothing on the net, absurd. Anyway the client has Win Server 2016, so I guess it's an ADFS 2016

Comment: Please read the article thoroughly. It answers all the questions related to configuration of application groups.

Comment: in the article you linked to me, the app is registered on adfs via the "application group" section, but it does not mention the difference with the "relying party trusts" section.
I was interested to understand if such a thing could be done, using saml and "relying party trusts".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211644/discussion-between-maweeras-and-microinfo).

Comment: Have a look at Passport - https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml